# EJB class not found, sessions bean for entity class issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

Recently I started learning JavaEE (using Netbeans 8+Glassfish 4) and encountered following problem :

I created EnterpriseApplication to test some EJB features; when creating Session Beans for Entity Class we can decide whether we want to create local interface, remote or none. If I choose none there is no problem, I can develop my application and everything seems fine. BUT if I choose local interface Netbeans generates additional file (FacadeLocal). Then when I try to access my bean (from -ejb project) using @EJB annotation in Servlet(inside -war project) I got 'class not found' exception beacuse server cannot find my bean.

I couldn't find any answer in the Internet, I'm newby at J2EE - hope you can help me. 
Greeting

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm#GIPIZ

Comment: Thanks, you pushed me in the right direction. Just if anyone will face this problem in future and wants fast solution : it's the matter of annotations, if you using local interface you need to add @Local annotation in your <class-name>Facade file (@Local({<class-name>FacadeLocal.class})